# Unable to retrieve all the data from a powershell using powershell.Invoke()

Tags: c#, sql, powershell

I am getting the list of all VM's hosted on a SCVMM machine.However, I am not getting the list of all the VM's.Only some 100-110 are shown.I am retrieving some specific properties from the list of VM's and storing them in the database which in turn will display information in the portal.The EXECUTEPS is a function which will display the list of VM's and store it in Collection variable.Below is my code,

```
Collection<PSObject> objVMDetailArrayCollection = ExecutePS("VMDETAILS", "");
string[] VMName=new string[objVMDetailArrayCollection.Count()];
int VMNumber=0;
foreach (PSObject objPSObject in objVMDetailArrayCollection)
{
    VMName[VMNumber] = objPSObject.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
    double ts = double.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["TotalSize"].Value.ToString());
    string vms = objPSObject.Properties["VirtualMachineState"].Value.ToString();
    double ma = double.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["MemoryAssignedMB"].Value.ToString());
    string status = objPSObject.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString();
    int cu = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["CPUUtilization"].Value.ToString());
    int pcu = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["PerfCPUUtilization"].Value.ToString());
    int pf = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["PerfMemory"].Value.ToString());
    int pdbr = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["PerfDiskBytesRead"].Value.ToString());
    int pnbw = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["PerfNetworkBytesWrite"].Value.ToString());
    DateTime ct = DateTime.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["CreationTime"].Value.ToString());
    string os = objPSObject.Properties["OperatingSystem"].Value.ToString();
    int cc = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["CPUCount"].Value.ToString());
    int memory = int.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["Memory"].Value.ToString());
    string hn = objPSObject.Properties["HostName"].Value.ToString();
    DateTime at = DateTime.Parse(objPSObject.Properties["AddedTime"].Value.ToString());

    for(int i=0;i<objArrayHosts1.Length;i++)
    {
        if(objArrayHosts1[i].Name==hn.Split('.')[0])
        {
            VMDetails[] objArrayVMDetails = objVMDetailsClient.GetVMDetailsByHostId(objArrayHosts1[i].HostId);
            if (objArrayVMDetails.Where(h => h.Name == VMName[VMNumber]).Count() > 0)
            {
                objVMDetailsClient.UpdateVMDetails(new VMDetails() { 
                    VMId = (objArrayVMDetails.Where(h => h.Name == VMName[VMNumber]).ToList())[0].VMId, 
                    HostId = objArrayHosts1[i].HostId, 
                    HostName = objArrayHosts1[i].Name, 
                    Name = VMName[VMNumber], 
                    VirtualMachineState = vms, 
                    TotalSize = ts, 
                    MemoryAssignedMB = ma, 
                    Status = status, 
                    CPUUtilization = cu, 
                    PerfCPUUtilization = pcu, 
                    PerfMemory = pf, 
                    PerfDiskBytesRead = pdbr, 
                    PerfNetworkBytesWrite = pnbw, 
                    CreationTime = ct, 
                    OperatingSystem = os, 
                    CPUCount = cc, 
                    Memory = memory, 
                    AddedTime = at });
            }
            else
            {
                objVMDetailsClient.CreateVMDetails(new VMDetails() { 
                    HostId = objArrayHosts1[i].HostId, 
                    HostName = objArrayHosts1[i].Name, 
                    Name = VMName[VMNumber], 
                    VirtualMachineState = vms, 
                    TotalSize = ts, 
                    MemoryAssignedMB = ma, 
                    Status = status, 
                    CPUUtilization = cu, 
                    PerfCPUUtilization = pcu, 
                    PerfMemory = pf, 
                    PerfDiskBytesRead = pdbr, 
                    PerfNetworkBytesWrite = pnbw, 
                    CreationTime = ct, 
                    OperatingSystem = os, 
                    CPUCount = cc, 
                    Memory = memory, 
                    AddedTime = at });
            }
        }
    }
    VMNumber++;
}
```

Comment: If you are not getting all the VMs then wouldn't that be the fault of the method call to ExecutePS("VMDetails", "") method? What is the value of returned by `objVMDetailArrayCollection.Count()` and does that represent all of the VMs you were expecting?

Comment: Also, what version of PowerShell are you using?  If you're using V3 or V4 you can take advantage of the fact the PSObject is dynamic.

Comment: objVMDetailArrayCollection.Count() gives the total number of VM's in all the hosts hosted in that scvmm machine.
Can you please elaborate on how we can use PSObject as Dynamic??

Comment: So is it the inner for loop that is somehow not iterating over all the VMs?  For instance, where does `objArrayHosts1` come from and what is the value of its `Length` property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell V3 or higher, you can simplify the code by taking advantage of the fact that PSObject supports dynamic e.g.:

```
foreach (dynamic psobj in objVMDetailArrayCollection)
{
    VMName[VMNumber] = psobj.Name.Value.ToString();
    double ts = double.Parse(psobj.TotalSize.Value.ToString());
    string vms = psobj.VirtualMachineState.Value.ToString();
    double ma = double.Parse(psobj.MemoryAssignedMB.Value.ToString());
    ...
```